# Cannot save changes when creating Custom tiles for O365 App Launcher in admin panel

Tags: office-365, dynamics-crm, microsoft, dynamics-365

i have came a cross a problem which is very mystical to me. I have be trying to create custom titles of Dynamic365 shortcut link to all users on Office365 portal landing page. I have a link do Dynamic365, i have name, link to icon which is 60x60 .jpg and Description set, but for some reason i just cannot save changes, the button is just grayed out. Can some one tell me, what am i doing wrong here? This should not be this hard as soo you have all this values set so, this is so odd.

I have been trying to test it in other tenant i have, but same thing.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot with this button?

Comment: yes, here is the screenshot https://prnt.sc/119ieo1

Answer (score 0):

I think there has been a change here recently. It might coincide with other changes MSFT has made with app tiles in the past few days (they changed the Dynamics app tile to drop into Power apps, completely confusing the end users) that had me scrambling to add more custom app tiles (I have 6-7 I have created in the past). I too am unable to add new app tiles to any tenancies - I have tried 3 separate tenants.

Update: this is an actual bug-----

Global admins can't add or modify custom app launcher tiles from the Microsoft 365 admin center
MO250626, Microsoft 365 suite, Last updated: April 14, 2021 8:24 PM
Estimated start time: March 31, 2021 8:00 PM

Title: Global admins can't add or modify custom app launcher tiles from the Microsoft 365 admin center

User Impact: Global admins can't add or modify custom app launcher tiles from the Microsoft 365 admin center.

More info: Admins will see a grayed out Save button that prevents them from adding or modifying custom app launcher tiles.

Current status: We've determined that a recent service update intended to improve a recent TypeScript update contained a code regression, causing impact. We're developing a fix which we anticipate will resolve the issue.

Scope of impact: Any global admin may experience impact.

Start time: Wednesday, March 31, 2021, 8:00 PM (3/1/2021, 12:00 AM UTC)

Root cause: A recent service update contained a code regression, causing impact.

Next update by: Thursday, April 15, 2021, 9:00 PM (4/16/2021, 1:00 AM UTC)